# Компиляция less в обозревателе

Tags: css, less

Пожалуйста, подскажите, каким образом я могу компилировать с less.js в обозревателе только когда мне это необходимо, а не автоматически?

Comment: На этом сайте вопросы задают на русском языке.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что здесь задают вопросы на русском

Answer (score 1):

```
#!watch
```

Добавить в конец URL, либо env поставить не development.